# Можно ли такое сделать в цикле for на java

Tags: java

формула выглядит так X1+X3+Xn-1  цикл складывает только не четный порядок х , допустим интервал от 0 до
2,5  шаг 0,5  ,  х0=0 х2=0,5 х3=1,5 х4=2 х5=2,5  цикл складывает х3 и х5  , но он не должен сложить х5 согласно формуле Хn-1. Можно ли это добавить в цикл

```
    double h = (b-a)/n;
    double count=0;
    double summ4 =0;

for (double x=a;x<=b;x=x+h){

        if(count%2!=0) {
            summ4 = summ4 + f(x);
        }
        count=count+1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеем вот такой промежуток:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
0.5   1   1.5   2   2.5
```

Т.к. нам нужно пропустить последнее нечетное слагаемое, то пропустим 2 последних слагаемых, среди которых 100% будет слагаемое с нечетным порядком, а с четным нас не интересует.

Например так:

```
//                  пропускаем 2 последних
for(double x = a; x <= b - (2 * h); x = x +h )
```

В вашем случае получаем такой промежуток:

```
 1    2    3
0.5   1   1.5
```

Comment: не работает если а=0  b=2 h=0.2 когда интервал 1234  должен сложить 1 и 3                                                                                                                for (double x=a;x<=b-(2*h);x=x+h){

            if(count%2!=0) {
                summ4 = summ4 + f(x);
            }
            count=count+1;
        }

Comment: понял , нужно 1*h               X1+X3+Xn-1

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Mobsman нет не нужно `1 * h` вы не знаете какое последнее слагаемое имеет порядок. Если оно будет четным, то в не пропустите последнее нечетное. У вас `count` это `int`?

Comment: да, но все правильно работает когда 1*h   X1+X3+Xn-1    и когда 2*h X2+X4+Xn-2   . Интеграл методом симпсона.

Comment: @Mobsman хмм ладно если вам так подходит, то хорошо :)

Comment: Нужно еще додумать верно работет 0 до 11 а если 1 до 11 то вроед не очень верно

Comment: @Mobsman дополните свой вопрос полным кодом пожалуйста. Где есть определение `a` `b`, `count` а то если и правда не верно работает, то давайте уж доведу до конца

Comment: Все верно , просто нужно доделать другую переменную для формулы. Спасибо